# How to restrict a pop-up to a single in screen in React Native?

Tags: popup, react-native

In my app, I have created multiple navigation screens. I have implemented a pop-up which appears every 90 seconds. But, this pop-up appears throughout the app. I want the pop-up to be limited to a single screen only. How can I restrict this pop-up?

Answer (score 0):

Have a try by using the React Context API and update the state of the context on every screen navigation so as the state updates then you can manage the popup as the screens change.

Check out the below example of Context API:

https://snack.expo.io/@gino8080/simple-react-native-context-api-example